# Imposition of Long Run and Short-Run restrictions in SVAR in R language

Tags: r, time-series, econometrics, vector-autoregression

I 'd like to ask a question about the imposition of LR and SR restrictions on an structural vector autoregressive model (SVAR) framework of analysis.

I read the documentation of the vars and svars packages, and I can see that restrictions are related solely to matrices A, B and AB, but not to F and S.

Does anyone know how to do so in the mentioned packages, or does anyone know any other ways of doing so?

Answer (score 1):

I will talk about A and B matrices. They pertain to short-run and, S = inverse(A)*B. So in vars package, you will specify matrices A and B individually.

For long-run restrictions, vars has function BQ() that imposes these restrictions like Blanchard and Quah(1989). It does not require specifying A or B (or F / S) matrices.